# How do you create an inline edit in backbone view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

so I am trying to get the fields in my backbone model being called in the view, editable and validated by the model. How do I go about doing that? I know there is an html way of doing  contenteditable="true" but I am looking for a more backbone oriented way or a way to actually make that validate too.

Here is my current code for my main.js file (but I am not trying to .append it I want it to stay in place and also trying to figure out how to get the field to be called specifically depending on which text they clicked on. Ultimately the button should change too (to save changes).

The main.js

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: 'date'
        },

        validate: function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        }

    });

App.Views.UserUpdate = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.Models.User,
        events: {
            'click .edit': 'editUserProfile'
        },

        editUserProfile: function(field) {
            var field = 
            $('#user').append('<input type="text" class="edit" placeholder="' + field+'" /> ' );
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.on('change', function() {
                this.render();
            }, this);
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.model.get('email'));
        }

    });
```

This is the jade file:

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/js/main.js")

        h4 User goes here with equal before it no space
        div(contenteditable="true") 
            form#user
                - var firstName = "John"
                - var lastName = "Smith"        
                label #{firstName} #{lastName}
                - var email = "test@test.com"
                label.edit #{email}
                - var phone = "555-555-5757"
                label #{phone}
                - var pin = "PIN: LIO20001"     
                label #{pin}
                - var birthday = "07/28/1982"   
                label #{birthday}
            button Post
        hr

        div.user User
            p
                button.edit Edit
```

Comment: Backbone like any MVC would allow you to have multiple views for same model and you can swap to an edit view on a click etc. Have a look at this example http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/1147_bb3and4/4/demo/index.html?#

Comment: understood but was trying to do a fancy inline edit when you click on the words

Comment: have you looked at http://etchjs.com/#demo. That uses contenteditable as well, but integrates with Backbone quite well

Answer (score 4):

I have created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/LTGjT/18/

You should assign the `contenteditable` and `id` for each editable label:

```
- var firstName = "John"
- var lastName = "Smith"        
label #{firstName} #{lastName}
- var email = "test@test.com"
label(contenteditable="true", id="email") #{email}
- var phone = "555-555-5757"
label(contenteditable="true", id="phone") #{phone}
- var birthday = "07/28/1982"   
label(contenteditable="true", id="birthday") #{birthday}
```

The reason is to recognize what label is being edited by getting the `event.target`, in your old code the `event.target` will always be the parent `div`.

Then in `backbone` listen to the `input` event for the change of the label then update the model:

```
App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: 'first',
        lastName: 'last',
        email: 'abc@abc.com',
        phone: '222',
        birthday: '01/01/2001'
    },

    initialize: function() {
    },

    validate: function (attrs) {
        if (!attrs.firstName) {
            return 'You must enter a real first name.';
        }
        if (!attrs.lastName) {
            return 'You must enter a real last name.';
        }
        if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
            return 'You must enter a real email.';
        }
        if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
            return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
        }
        if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
            return 'You must enter a real city.';
        }
    }

});

App.Views.UserUpdate = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: App.Models.User,
    events: {
        'click button' : 'saveHandler'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.render();
        console.log(this.model);
        $('[contenteditable=true]').on('input', function(e){
            var field = e.target.id;
            var value = e.target.innerText;
            self.model.set(field, value);
            logUser(self.model);
        });
        self.model.on('change', function(){
            $('button').show();
        });
    },

    saveHandler: function(e) {
        //Validate & Save logic
        //this.model.save()
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).hide();
    },

    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#user-view').html());
        this.$el.html(template({user: this.model.toJSON()}));            
        $('body').prepend(this.$el);
        logUser(this.model);
    }

});
```